# setup piwik with golang

Tags: go, matomo

I want to setup piwik with go server, I tried searching for it in google
the only relevant result that came up was [piwik.go zoey middleware](https://gitlab.sedara.io/zoey/middleware/blob/bf02334f5e5e317a0524a5e7d7efd851f40f7af4/piwik/piwik.go)
but it doesnt have any info on how to use the middleware
if anyone could point me in a right direction, to configure piwik or an alternative analytics platform suitable with go it will be really helpfull

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found your question and decided to write a middleware for piwik. You have to set up piwik on a PHP server first, then you can use this middleware to track your requests: https://github.com/veecue/piwik-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Piwik itself is a PHP project, you can not set it up using Go.

The repository you linked to is a couple of methods to send Piwik specific data to the Piwik API.

Comment: Thanks @Gerben Jacobs 
Is there any alternative to piwik suitable for golang?

Comment: For ref, there's https://github.com/usefathom/fathom which looks promising.